# Intellij 2021.3: Maven not able to resolve dependencies after update to intellij 2021.3

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

Things worked fine in 2021.2 but when same project opened in 2021.3 then stated to got following error

```
http://0.0.0.0/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-default-http-blocker has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.domain.sub-domain.project:private-commons:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): transfer failed for http://0.0.0.0/com/domain/sub-domain/project/private-repo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Cannot resolve junit:junit:4.12
Cannot resolve org.apache.camel:camel-test:2.23.0
Cannot resolve com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-glacier:1.11.415
```

[image: screen shoot]

Comment: Clean caches and restart.  If that does not help, recreate the project from the sources.

Comment: tried, didn't help

Comment: Check [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677156/could-not-transfer-artifact-from-to-central-intellij/71234005#71234005) for solving the issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

2021.3 IDE version has updated the version of the bundled Maven to `3.8.1`. In [this version](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html), Maven blocks the access to `http` repositories by default. Before that, Maven itself has [moved from using the http repositories](https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https).

So now one needs to explicitly configure Maven to allow `http` repositories if they are used in the project. E.g. in `settings.xml` add a mirror to your http repository that allows HTTP:

```xml
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>my-repo-mirror</id>
        <name>My Repo HTTP Mirror</name>
        <url>http://url-to.my/repo</url>
        <mirrorOf>my-repo</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

You can also check the related discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002852/2000323 for ways to configure it.

Another option is to specify older Maven version in IDE: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Maven home path**.

Comment: This is important information.    The discarding of a given repository could be reported much better though.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen in next IDE versions we will add detection of such cases with possible quick fix suggestions about how to fix this.

Comment: @Andrey I was thinking of Mavens own reporting.  If intellij can be more informative thats even better.

Comment: for me just change Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Maven home path** to **User Maven Wrapper**

Comment: Every time I upgrade the IntelliJ version it deletes all the settings, I have 16 projects, and I must reconfigure after every upgrade. IntelliJ is not so intelligent after all!